# Angular Material -md-grid-list content

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use `md-grid-tile` of angular material.The Issue I am facing is content of `md-grid-tile` is aligned center.How to make to work it from Start

```
    <md-content layout-padding> 

         <md-grid-list md-cols="6"
            md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3" md-gutter-gt-md="16px"
            md-gutter-gt-sm="8px" md-gutter="4px"> 
                    <md-grid-tile
                    ng-repeat="room in floorDetails.roomDetails"
                    ng-style="{'background': '#f2f2f2'}"
                    md-colspan-gt-sm="3"
                    md-rowspan-gt-sm="2">  



                                <div layout="row"  layout-align="center center">
                                <b >Room1</b>
                                </div>
                                 <div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
                                         <md-card class="md-card" ng-repeat="bed in room.bedIds">
                                             <md-card-content>

                                             </md-card-content>
                                         </md-card>
                                     </div>
                             </div>
              </md-grid-tile>        
      </md-grid-list>
```

Current snap

[image: Current snap]

Desired snap

[image: desired snap]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to provide a codepen/plunkr with an example next time, people are more inclined to help you if they have sample code to play around with.

You should read up on [angular-material layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction). You are mainly missing a `<div layout="column" layout-fill>` container inside of your `md-grid-tile`. The `layout-fill` makes the container fill the whole tile.

You can then adjust the size of your cards with fixed css sizes or flex them. The example flexes them horizontally which may not be desired.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/mVBXyG)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (yet) with Angular 2 Material Design bits